# Why am I seeing zeros being inserted into my MySQL DB?

Tags: php

In my MySQL DB, I'm seeing effectively blank records inserted into my messages table before a proper and expected insert:

```
id, user_id, message, rating
43, 0, 0, 0
44 23498745, test, 0
```

The record with the id of 43 shouldn't exist, for some reason its inserting zeros.  I'm not sure why because my if condition is checking that `$message` has some sort of value

```
if(isset($message) && !empty($message) && !is_NULL($message)){
            $data['text'] = 'Your message has been saved';
            $stmt = $pdo->query('INSERT INTO messages (user_id, message, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
            $stmt->execute([$chat_id, $message, 0]);
            Request::sendMessage($data);
 }
```

Even putting an `exit;` statement after the call to `sendMessage()` doesn't do anything.  I can't see anything wrong with this.

How can I prevent these blank records being inserted?

Comment: Are there another place in your code where you run `insert into messages`?

Comment: in your condition you are checking 3 steep. see your messages are coming 0 so the 3 steep are passing true and it's inserting date into database. add one more like this if(isset($message) && !empty($message) && !is_NULL($message) && $message!=0)

Comment: @jualahmed  0 is considered empty.  OP could actually replace all 3 of those checks with just `if(!empty($message))` and it would be the same thing.